# DOM focus hijack and dragging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, material-ui

I'm not sure if this is doable.

---

I'm using material-ui treeview component which would hijack the focus from a `li` element to its parent `ul`. [source code](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/818138449fb090555606e800f7de7db960db7aa8/packages/x-tree-view/src/TreeItem/TreeItem.tsx#L294)

A minial reproducable code: [playground](https://playcode.io/1702260)

```js
import React from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const dragOnList = (event) => {
    // Never see this log
    console.log('dragOnList', event.target)
  };

  const dragOnItem = (event) => {
    // And this neither
    console.log('dragOnItem', event.target)
  };

  const focusHijack = (event)=>
  {
    // !Hijack focus from item to list!
    document.getElementById('list').focus()
  }

  // Attempt to start dragging on any of the elements
  return (
    <ul id='list' draggable tabIndex={-1} onDragStart={dragOnList}>
      <li onFocus={focusHijack} tabIndex={-1} draggable onDragStart={dragOnItem}><div>List Item 1</div></li>
      <li onFocus={focusHijack} tabIndex={-1} draggable onDragStart={dragOnItem}><div>List Item 2</div></li>
      <li onFocus={focusHijack} tabIndex={-1} draggable onDragStart={dragOnItem}><div>List Item 3</div></li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

But none of these elements, `li` and `ul`, would be able to drag.

I'm wondering if there is a workaround which could make the dragging work while the focus has been hijacked?